# Determine if the sequence $a_{n+1}=\arctan{a_n}$ is convergent and compute its limit.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Determine if the sequence $\{a\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ defined by $$a_1>0\\a_{n+1} =\arctan{a_n}$$ is convergent and compute its limit.

Will Banachs Fixed Point theorem be of any help here?

**My attempt.**

We note that the recurrence relation is of the form $x_{n+1}=f(x_n),$ let's introduce the help function $f(x)=\arctan{x}.$ I know that the equation $f(x)=0$ has a root $x=0$, so I'll choose an interval $I=[0,\frac{1}{2}].$ In order to use the fixed point theorem, the following criterias have to be met:

1. $f(x)$ has to be defined and continuous on $I$ (OK!)
2. $f(x)\in I$ for each $x\in I.$ (OK!)
3. There should exist a $0\leq k<1$ such that $|f'(x)|\leq k<1.$

If all of these are met, it follows that $a_n$ converges to the unambiguous root of the equation $x=f(x)$.

The third criteria is where I run into problems. I get that

$$|f'(x)|=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\leq1,$$

So my $k$ is $1$, but I need it to be less than one! How can I go around this problem?

Comment: Of course, $x\mapsto \arctan(x)$ is a contraction of $[0,+\infty)$ since $\arctan'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\leq 1$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio don't you need a strict bound away from 1?

Comment: @qbert: in the standard version of Banach's theorem yes, you need it, but you may invoke the Caccioppoli's version: we have a weak contraction over $[0,\pi/2]$, which is compact.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Ah, thank you for the reference, as always!

Answer (score 1):

Any weak contraction over a compact metric space has a unique fixed point by the Banach-Caccioppoli theorem, hence we may state that $a_n\to 0$ since $x\mapsto \arctan(x)$ is a weak contraction over $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. On the other hand, this is an overkill, since our sequence is clearly non-negative and decreasing, so it is convergent, and there are not so many $L\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $L=\arctan L$.

Comment: Please see the attempt in my edit. How do I get correct $k$?

Comment: @Parseval: you cannot bound $|\arctan'|$ with something less than $1$ since $\arctan'(0)=1$. On the other hand you may replace the Banach theorem (hypothesis: strong contraction over a metric space) with the Banach-Caccioppoli theorem (hypothesis: weak contraction over a compact metric space). Anyway, you do not need such *finesse*: convergence towards zero is trivial.

Comment: We've never learned the Caccioppoli theorem and It's nowhere in my book. And I have no idea what you are talking about when you say "compact metric space". Never heard of it in my Calculus I class. How is it trivial? I have too many questions to list them all in this comment section.

Comment: @Parseval: that is not my fault, and nothing stops you from googling Banach-Caccioppoli. Convergence to zero is trivial since, as I wrote, *our sequence is clearly non-negative and decreasing, so it is convergent, and there are not so many $L\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $L=\arctan L$*.

Comment: My point was that, if we have not covered that theorem, we should definitely not use it. This problem gives 5 points on an exam and I don't think that sentence in itallic warrants 5 points.

Comment: @Parseval: it does not change the fact that such sentence *is* a solution.

Comment: Im sure it is, and I do not doubt your math skills for one second. However it is not interesting to me if it is a solution or not, what is interesting is to actually get 5 points on that question using what my university wants me to use. This means that I really need to understand things otherwise it's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

For $x> 0,$

$$\tag 1 0<\arctan x = \int_0^x \frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt < \int_0^x 1\,dt =x.$$

Thus your sequence $a_n$ is positive and strictly decreasing. It therefore has a limit $L\ge 0.$ Since $L = \lim a_n = \lim a_{n+1} = \lim \arctan a_n = \arctan L,$ we must have $L=0$ (otherwise $L>0$ and $\arctan L < L$ by $(1),$ contradiction).

Comment: Please see the attempt in my edit. Would that work?

Comment: I don't see how it follows that $a_n$ is strictly decreasing, by observing your equation line. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Parseval  $0<a_1 \implies  0 <\arctan a_1 < a_1.$ But $\arctan a_1 = a_2.$ So $0<a_2 < a_1.$ Continue ...